# Not able to upload image in webapp/resources/images folder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am not able to upload image with this code, although it is not showing any error but at the same time image is also not saving in folder.

```
MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();

String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "resources/images/" + product.getProductId() + ".png");

if(productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()){
    try {
        productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        System.out.println("image edited then saved ");
        
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving failed", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The intention is ok for this kind of solution but try for alternative solutions.

Also you will loose these images once the server restarts

Comment: that path is not writable btw, or it should not be writable.